# Which services can be managed by AWS SAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

Which services can be managed by the [AWS SAM (Serverless Application Model) framework](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/what-is-sam.html)?

AWS Docs seem to list contradicting information:

- https://aws.amazon.com/serverless/ lists plenty of services as serverless, incl. Lambda, Fargate, ..., SNS, SQS, ... DynamoDB, S3.
- [SAM resource reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification-resources-and-properties.html) lists only: Api, Application, Function, HttpApi, LayerVersion, SimpleTable, StateMachine.

Yet, I cannot find any mention in the SAM docs on how to create an S3 bucket.

An example doubt is - can I have an S3 bucket created using SAM framework?
Can SAM deploy to Fargate too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any CloudFormation component as part of your SAM config file. As noted in the [SAM developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-specification.html):

> AWS SAM templates are an extension of AWS CloudFormation templates, with some additional components that make them easier to work with. For the full reference for AWS CloudFormation templates, see [AWS CloudFormation Template Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-reference.html) in the AWS CloudFormation User Guide.